# Pubnub Subscription Error

Tags: pubnub

I'm using `pubnub` in my Application. It works fine when subscription is ok, but when subscription error occur at that time my App crashes

I tried to put that code in the try and catch blocks but nothing changed.
This problem happens when `PubnubService` class for notification.

`Pubnubservice` class is used for background service to receive pubnub Notifications.

Here is the image:

[image]

Comment: Looks like a string index error?  Can you show your Java Source?

Comment: Thnx.. Btw i solved this issue... This issue occured because i m making substring from one string Substring ("{") but when error occurs this bracket is not comming thats y my app is crashing... so first i search specific word from my STRING and if that word presend then and then make sub string....

Answer (score 0):

Just pasting answer here:

This issue ocurred because i m making substring from one string Substring ("{") but when error occurs this bracket is not coming thats why my app is crashing... so first i search specific word from my STRING and if that word present then and then make sub string.